# Firewall Capable of Handling 100Mbs Down

Tags: firewall

We have 100Mbs down internet and I'm trying to find a firewall that will not slash the speed down to much.  I've tried with a Sonicwall Tz210 and a year old cisco ASA 5 series.  They both cut the speed down to 50Mbs and 30Mbs respectively.  Does anyone have any experience with new firewalls capable of delivering better throughput ?

Comment: Did you check to make sure bandwidth management was disabled on the Sonicwall? Also if you're running filtering/AV it will have an impact on speed.

Comment: Voring to close - that is a shopping question, off topic per FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get brutal: Mikrotik CCR (CLoud COre Router). Has 2 cores per port, dedicated. Not expensive. The speed you get from that will make the "100mbit" a sad joke. You can easily firewall 6-8 gigabit with complex rules.

Comment: Do you know when will the Mikrotik be available ?  ISP has it as pre-order ?

Comment: Soon. They wait for RouterOS v6 to be finished (in RC6 state) for that one. It is an impressive item, though. FOr 100mbit an 1100AH2 should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

The Tz210 should work at 100Mbps according to [Tz210 specs](http://o-www.sonicwall.com/us/en/products/TZ_210.html)  But as noted on that page and by @Cole, enabling some options will reduce throughput  The Tz210 Stateful Throughput is rated at 200Mbps but UTM performance is around 50Mbps.

You will likley need something with more processing power to get your full 100Mbps and naturally there is a cost

Comment: Yeah I fooled around with the bandwidth management didn't make a noticeable difference.